# What is the National Identification Number of Dutch citizens?

Tags: usa, paperwork, esta, dutch-citizens

On the ESTA form for entry to the USA they ask for a National Identification Number, which should not be the same as a Personal Identification Number.

What kind of number is it and where do I find it?

Answer (score 12):

That'd be [the BSN](https://www.expatica.com/nl/about/gov-law-admin/the-dutch-bsn-your-national-identification-number-in-the-netherlands-1529368/).

> The Dutch Citizen Service Number (BSN) is your official national
>   identification in the Netherlands. It replaced the old social security
>   number (sofinummer) in 2007. The Dutch BSN was introduced in July 2007
>   to enhance the efficiency of government administration and improve
>   public service delivery to citizens.
>
> The BSN in the Netherlands is closely linked with the national
>   register (BRP). Registering with the BRP is key to getting your
>   Citizen Service Number in the Netherlands. Once you have registered
>   with the BRP, you will be issued with a Dutch BSN which will be needed
>   for any interactions with the Dutch government or public services,
>   from receiving social security or healthcare to enrolling for study or
>   paying tax. This means that the BSN functions as a social security
>   number, a national identification number and a tax number in the
>   Netherlands.
>
> Whereas the sofinummer was the responsibility of the Dutch tax
>   authority (Belastingdienst), the Dutch BSN is administered by the
>   Ministry of the Interior (BZK) and issued by the local municipalities.
>   It is a unique 8 or 9 digit number which can be found on Dutch
>   passports, national ID cards and driving licences.

Comment: And for completeness: For those who had a SoFi number before the introduction of the BSN, their SoFi number became their BSN. BRP stands for "BasisRegister Persoonsregistratie"

Comment: Actually BRP stands for "Basisregistratie Personen".